# Memory leak in Xamarin Forms app when using DI in a Task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xamarin, dependency-injection, memory-leaks

I am creating a Xamarin Forms application, and I am using the Xamarin Profiler to show that I have a memory leak.  I have tracked the memory leak down to where it is happening, but I can't understand WHY it is happening.

I have a class (we will call it MyClass for now). And that class is using a Timer to call a service once every second.  That service makes a REST call to retrieve a bunch of information, and then serializes the results back into an object....

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass : ContentPage
{
    private readonly IMyService myService;

    public MyClass() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        StartTimer();
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        Task.Run(async() =>
        {
            while(true)
            {
                myService = ((App)App.Current)
                    .serviceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<IMyService>();

                //--- everytime I call myService.GetSystemStatus(), my allocated memory continues to rise

                MyResponse response = await myService.GetSystemStatus();
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    // update the UI here...
                });
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyService (Singleton):

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IMyHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

    public MyService(IMyHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<MyResponse> GetSystemStatus()
    {
        return await httpClientFactory.Create().GetAsync<MyResponse>(
            "http://example.com/api/status"
        );
    }
}
```

MyHttpClientFactory (Singleton):

```
public class MyHttpClientFactory : IMyHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public MyHttpClientFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public MyHttpClient Create()
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyHttpClient>();
    }
}
```

MyHttpClient:

```
public class MyHttpClient : IDisposable
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyHttpClient ()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    }

    public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url) where T : new()
    {
        string s = await GetStringAsync(url);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(s);
    }

    public async Task<string> GetStringAsync(string url)
    {
        using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

My services are defined as follows:

```
public partial class App : Application

    public ServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public App()
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(services);
        serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
  
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient<MyHttpClient>("MyHttpClient", x =>
        {
            x.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IMyHttpClientFactory, MyHttpClientFactory>();
        services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
    }
}
```

Best I can tell, the memory is going up because I am referencing the DI MyService inside a separate thread.  But I am not sure if this is the reason or if there is something else that would be causing the leak?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks!

Comment: Creating a new HttpClient every time you need one is a well documented anti-pattern/memory leak.

Comment: I am not creating a new instance. The HttpClientFacrory I am using handles that and returns the singleton instance of the already created client. So I don't think that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers....

I finally figured out the source of the memory leak.

The problem was that I was referencing "MyService" like this:

```
myService = ((App)App.Current)
   .serviceProvider
   .GetRequiredService<IMyService>();
```

The problem was that the `serviceProvider` object was a public property on my App.  So each time I referenced the provider inside my loop, it was creating the leak.

To get around this, I added an abstract method to each of my pages that implemented MyClass to return the service correctly using DI.  This has corrected my memory leak issue....

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Please add to answer the **code snippet** that solved the problem.

Comment: Also, to be sure I understand: each call to `GetRequiredService` returned a new instance? If so, then your more fundamental problem was `MyHttpClientFactory`. If you always called `static` methods on that, instead of calling `GetRequiredService` directly in your other classes, and those methods were designed to re-use a single instance, then there would not have been a problem in the first place. In general, having both a **factory** AND **DI** is "overkill": those are two techniques that solve the same problem (when properly used).

Comment: OR if you stay with DI, then the REAL problem is wherever you DECLARE the provider of `IMyService`. All DI libraries support a notion of SINGLETON: A service that can be asked for many times, and always returns the SAME INSTANCE. There should have been no need to alter your classes. If you use a singleton service, then you can ask for that service from anywhere, as often as you desire, without any memory leaks or other issues. That's the true "reputable source" answer to your question. (But your question does not show the DI declaration of that service, so its not possible to show the fix.)

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand from your code and your comments, it looks like you're looping by calling `StartTimer()` inside the `Device.StartTimer()` method.

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms), `Device.StartTimer()` is recurring and will occur every X seconds, depending of your `interval` parameter.

By removing the call to `StartTimer()` (the one between `t.Dispose()` and `return false` of `MyClass.StartTimer`, your code should work as expected and you will not create a new timer every x seconds

Comment: If I return false though, it won't keep recurring right? I need it to run oce every second after the thread executes. So I could return true, which would work, but what if the operation takes longer than a second? That is why I was doing it this way, but that could possibly be my problem?

Comment: If you need to do it every x seconds, you should return `true` indeed, because the timer of the device will handle it for you. What you're doing here is kinda the same but manually and you're creating a new timer everytime (that might explain the memory leak, to be confirmed).
If you need to do it infinitly, then you should never return `false` (which shouldn't be the case in my opinion). So you need to find an exit condition at which point you will stop to fetch your data.

Comment: @yguerin - There may be a good reason for doing this instead of a fixed-interval repeating timer: it ensures that timer events don't "pileup" if the "work" takes too long. (If that is needed, there are cleaner ways to do this than the code in question - but that is a separate topic.)

Comment: @yguerin is correct.  That is the reason that I was doing it that way.  I have simplified the code a bit to get rid of timers altogether, but I am still getting the same memory leak issue...

Answer (score 1):

What could be the cause of the leak:

Your `MyHttpClient` class implements the `IDisposable` interface, yet the code to use an instance of this class is not leveraging the disposable nature of the object.
Even though the internal `HttpClient` instance is wrapped in a using statement, the `MyHttpClient` instance will not be disposed of as you would expect.

```
    // from MyHttpClient class
    public async Task<MyResponse> GetSystemStatus()
    {
        // no using statement here
        return await httpClientFactory.Create().GetAsync<MyResponse>(
            "http://example.com/api/status"
        );
    }

    // should be:
    public async Task<MyResponse> GetSystemStatus()
    {
        using (var client = await httpClientFactory.Create())
        {
            return await client.GetAsync<MyResponse>("http://example.com/api/status");
        }
    }
```

Another thing to try is to change the location of the resolution of the `MyService` instance to inside the Task since this is where it is used. This will allow the task to own the resource, and allow it to be collected when the task is complete.

```
private void StartTimer()
{
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(async() =>
        {
            // resolve the service here
            myService = ((App)App.Current)
                            .serviceProvider
                            .GetRequiredService<IMyService>();
            

            MyResponse response = await myService.GetSystemStatus();

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                // update the UI here...
            });
        });
        t.Wait();
        t.Dispose();

        StartTimer();
        return false;
    });
}
```

A couple of additional observations of your code:
In your `HttpClientFactory`'s `Create()` method, you are resolving an instance of your client from the DI container.
Your `MyHttpClient` class has a default constructor which means the resolution is not needed since there are no additional dependencies requiring DI support.
Your code could simply return a `new MyHttpClient()` instance from the `Create()` method without the need for DI.

Your `MyHttpClient` also implements the `IMyHttpClient` interface, but your factory returns the concrete type. This means you need to **either** remove the interface as unnecessary **or** change the return type to be the interface type since the interface is redundant unless it is used.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am out of town today but will try this tomorrow and see if that makes a difference.... Thanks!

Comment: So I looked at this a bit and it doesn't appear to be the problem.  While MyHttpClient does implement IDisposable, I wouldn't want to dispose of the HttpClient object each iteration of the loop, as Microsoft states that you want to re-use the HttpClient and not create a new instance each time.  Your other changes all make sense, but didn't help with the memory leak issue....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your timer logic is the cause of the leak.

But in case it is useful to you, here is a clean way to do work periodically, yet if work takes a long time, avoid events "piling up".

Given await/async, no Timer is needed.
(There is an alternative solution that starts/stops a *single* System.Timers.Timer, but I won't go into that here.)

Replace StartTimer() declaration with the following:

```cs
        /// <summary> Runs until keepRunning() returns false.
        /// Delays by "msecDelay" AFTER finishing the previous loop's non-UI work. </summary>
        private void StartTaskLoopWhileKeepRunning(Func<bool> keepRunning, int msecDelay = 250)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (keepRunning())
                {
                    // Do non-UI work here.
                    // ... possibly slow work ...

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        // NOTE: This work will run in parallel with the next delay.
                        // ... Do UI work here. ...
                    });

                    // Non-UI thread sleeps for msec.
                    await Task.Delay(msecDelay);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  It didn't solve the problem with my memory issue, but I agree this is a bit cleaner...